# Delete folders from SD card

Tags: java, android, file

I have some folders in my SD card. I want to delete folders in closing activity i.e in onDestroy() callback. for example : I have folderA, folderB and FolderC. I am able to delete folderA and FolderB. these folder contains files(.zip, .pdf etc) but folderC I am not able to delete it contains folders, subfolders and files. Below is my code.

```
deletUnZipedFiles(File file){
file = new File(MainActivity.root_sd,"/folderC");   
if (file.isDirectory()) {
   String[] children = file.list();
    for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
    boolean success = deletUnZipedFiles(new File(file, children[i]));
    System.out.println("status of unziped delet"+success);
    if (!success) {
      return false;
     }
    }
  }
  // The directory is now empty so delete it
 //return file.delete();
}
```

Why folderC is not deleting. I am using same procedure for folderA and folderB.

Thanks

Comment: Have u added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> permission in your android manifest file?

Comment: why do you commented this --> //return file.delete();

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for delete folder. You need to pass File object like :

```
File file = new File("C:\\A\\B"); 
DeleteRecursive(file);

void DeleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {

 if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
    for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
        DeleteRecursive(child);

    fileOrDirectory.delete();

    }
```